# On page load: Only show specific information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that is going to have many many toggles on it, some created dynamically. I was wondering if I could load a page, which shows only a specific div, but the moment the user clicks a button a toggle is created (done this part) and the user is unable to see the version of the page that only shows one specific div unless they delete all the other content on the page.

I do not know if I have explained that well at all:

**Start off showing only this content**

[image]

**On clicking the save button only show this...**

[image]

My code does part of this already. Just honestly cannot work out how to even start the on page load part. I have looked at the jQuery on page load function but don't know if this is the best or only route.

```js
   //hide text onclick
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var $p = $('p#menu_title');
                $("input#save_first_prod").click(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $p.css('display', 'none');
                });
            });

 function toggle_visibility(id) {
                var e = document.getElementById(id);
                if (e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display == '')
                    e.style.display = 'none';
                else
                    e.style.display = 'block';
            }
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: visible; 
}
div#first_product{
width: 50%;
margin-left: 301px;   
}

div#red_head{
background-color: #ed1c24;
height: 40px;
color: #fff;
padding-left: 15px;
line-height: 35px;
}

div#first_product{
background-color: #f1f1f2; 
height: 100%;
}

h3#menu{
color: #6d6e70;
padding-left: 15px;
}

/*OUTSIDE TOGGLE BUTTON*/
#products_tog_but{
background-color: #f8f9f9;
border: 1.5px dashed #999999;
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

div#hide_btn{
width:50%;
margin-left: 301px;
}
```

```html
div id="hide_btn">
        <button id="products_tog_but" onclick="toggle_visibility('first_product')">Hello!</button>
        </div>
        
     <!-- TOGGLE BTN SECTION-->   
        <div id="first_product">
            <div id="red_head">
                <p id="menu_title" class ="hidden" onclick="hideText('text1')" > Add your first menu item</p>
            </div>
            <h3 id="menu">Menu Section</h3>

            <form name="first_prod" id="first_prod" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="testing.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" >               

                <label id="cat_label" name="cat_label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="cat_name" name="cat_name" value="">

                <label id="desc_label" name="desc_label">Description</label>
                <input type="text" id="cat_desc" name="cat_desc" value="">

                <input type="Submit" id="save_first_prod" name="save_first_prod" onclick="toggle_visibility('first_product')" value=" + ADD"> 

            </form>


        </div>
```

Comment: are you trying to show something on loading time (before the `$(document).ready` function) or just on first interaction? You might need to clarify your question. it's not easy to understand what you're trying to achieve